# I need a Powershell Script which sends some information via Email

Tags: powershell

I Wrote a Powershell Script which will Get the status of the services and it will save the results to a Txt file. And it will trigger an email with the TXT file as an attachment. But i need the results to be sent as a Body of the Email in a Tabular Format.

Below is the Script i wrote.

```
Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status, Description |
    Out-File C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Report\ServiceStatus.txt

Send-MailMessage -From ABC@Gmail.com `
    -Subject "Services Status" `
    -To XYZ@gmail.com `
    -Attachments C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Report\ServiceStatus.txt `
    -Body "Donot Reply to this email" `
    -DeliveryNotificationOption OnFailure,OnSuccess,Delay `
    -Port 25 -Priority High -SmtpServer 11.19.17.78
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ConvertTo-Html` to generate an HTML table from the service objects, and then make sure to set the `-BodyAsHtml` switch parameter when calling `Send-MailMessage`:

```
# generate html table
$html = Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* |Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status, Description |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Title "Windos Services running on $env:COMPUTERNAME"

# prepare arguments
$mailArgs = @{
    From                       = 'ABC@Gmail.com' 
    Subject                    = 'Services Status' 
    To                         = 'XYZ@gmail.com'
    Body                       = ($html -join '')
    BodyAsHtml                 = $true
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure,OnSuccess,Delay' 
    Port                       = 25 
    Priority                   = 'High' 
    SmtpServer                 = '11.19.17.78'
}

# send message
Send-MailMessage @mailArgs
```

---

Given that `Get-Service` doesn't returnthe service description, you may want to use `Get-CimInstance Win32_Service` instead.

Since WMI uses it's own query language, we'll need to translate the displayname wildcard - for this we can use `WildcardPattern.ToWql()`:

```
# define wildcard pattern
$displayNamePattern = "Windows*"

# convert to WQL query filter
$wqlFilter = [WildcardPattern]::new($displayNamePattern).ToWql()

# now we can query WMI for the service details and build the table
$html = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "DisplayName LIKE '${wqlFilter}'" |Select-Object -Property DisplayName, State, Description |ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Title "Windos Services running on $env:COMPUTERNAME"

# rest of script remains the same ...
```

Comment: Description of the Service is not Coming in the report

Comment: @SV12VS That's because `Get-Service` doesn't return the description, you'd have to use `Get-CimInstance Win32_Server` for that

Comment: Could you please help me with that particular line of the Script?

Is it that i need to replace Get-Service -DisplayName Windows* with "CimInstance Win32_Server"

Comment: @SV12VS I've updated the answer to show how to do the same with `Get-CimInstance Win32_Service` :)

Comment: @SV12VS What version of PowerShell are you using? Try replacing `[WildcardPattern]` with `[System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]`

Comment: I am using PS Version 4.0. 
[System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern] even this is not working. getting the following error 

Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern] does not contain a method named 'new'.
At C:\Users\Downloads\Get_Services.ps1:7 char:1
+ $wqlFilter = [System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::new($displayNamePat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: `(New-Object System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern $displayNamePattern).ToWql()` should do

Comment: Is it possible to put if condition and and check if it Gives the results only for the Stopped Services ?

Comment: @SV12VS Feel free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: Asked a New Question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75794645/i-need-a-powershell-script-to-get-the-real-time-status-of-a-service